# Appcelerator adding elements before and after specific elements

Tags: layout, view, appcelerator

Using appcelerator, how do you go about inserting elements before and after specific elements. Such as 
`<View id='element'>Some Content</View>`

Using $.element.add() the new element will be inside it but i need it to go either before or after. In simple terms is there an equivalent to .before and.after in jQuery?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `insertAt` ([docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-insertAt)).

If the parent view's layout is `horizontal` or `vertial`, then you'll see the children views displayed according to their array positions.

Comment: Works like a charm, made .insertBefore and .insertAfter from this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 workarounds for insert elements before the actual views:

1. Save the $.elements.children in a array, and unshift the new elements to the array, and add all those views in array to the $.elements;
2. While you adding the views, set the left or top property (depending on your design), and every time you add a new child, run a loop of the children and increase their left or top property; ex (child views with 200):

   $.elements.children[0].left = 0;
   $.elements.children[1].left = 200;
   $.elements.children[2].left = 400;